# regex for at least one character

Tags: c++, regex, boost

How to check if string contains at least one character? I want to eliminate strings where are only special characters, so I've decided that the easiest way is to check if there is at least one character or digit, so I've created `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` but none of these work.

```
boost::regex noSpecialCharacters("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
boost::regex noSpecialCharacters2("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}");

string tab[SIZE] = {"father", "apple is red"};


for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
  if (!boost::regex_match(tab[i], noSpecialCharacters)) {
    puts("This is it!");
  } else {
    puts("or not");
  }

if (!boost::regex_match(tab[i], noSpecialCharacters2)) {
  puts("This is it!");
} else {
    puts("or not");
  }
}
```

for "apple is red" the answer is correct but for "father" it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you using `noSpecialCharacters` in _both_ `if` statements?

Comment: My bad. I will change that. But still - it doesn't work

Comment: "it doesn't work" is the bane of the problem-fixing industry. Please state what you expect and what you actually get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apple is red` won't match because, as per [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html) (my bold):

> Note that the result is true only if the expression matches the **whole** of the input sequence.

That means the spaces make it invalid. It then goes on to say (again, my bold):

> If you want to search for an expression somewhere **within** the sequence then use `regex_search`.

If all you're looking for is one valid character somewhere in there, you can just use `regex_match()` with `".*[a-zA-Z0-9].*"` or `regex_search()` with `"[a-zA-Z0-9]"`.

Comment: Ok, so what I should do to find at least one character or digit in any kind of string? And as I wrote for "apple is red" the answer is correct... but for "father" it is not

Comment: Ok, this is it! Thank you. And I thought that it returns false it found some of these characters...